# ubicación del archivo de base de datos MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

si me pudieran ayudar.

Estoy intentado generar el instalador de mi aplicacion en c# y con base de datos en MySql, estoy usando el install shield de Visual Studio 2012, y necesito ubicar el archivo de mi base de datos, pero no logro encontrarlo, solo tengo el modelo *mwb pero no se si eso me servirá.

Comment: En mysql no hay archivo de base de datos, ya que la db esta junto al servicio del motor de la db. Si vas a distribuir la db junto a la aplicacion deberias poner los script, con las instrucciones de CREATE TABLE, etc que cree la estructura y los INSERT para los datos. Salvo que realicen un `dump` de la db y a patir de este realices un restore

Comment: desde phpmyadmin o el mismo worbench puedes generar un respaldo en diferentes formatos como sql, xls, etc....

Comment: @DiegoAvila uso workbench, me podrías indicar o ayudar a generar dicho respaldo?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini entonces tendría que incluir en mi instalador los script?  Otra consulta relacionada: que archivo o version de Mysql debo incluir en mi distribución? si es que no tiene instalado Mysql el pc donde se instale la aplicación?

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/2133/~/back-up-and-restore-mysql-databases-using-mysql-workbench-6-or-8

Comment: El tema es que la ejecucion de los script no va a ser automatizada, va requerir que ejecuten manualmente o quizas si debsarrollas algo que levante los archivos de script y ejecute, por supuesto despues de haber instalado el motor de mysql. La version deberia ser la misma con la cual desarrollaste.

Comment: Ademas de tener que mandar el motor, encenderlo cada vez que prende su pc, y configurarlo, vas a necesitar modificar la cadena de conexion de tu programa para que se conecte a esa nueva base de datos.